# How to define uri in codeigniter to match method that has been called inside another

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

In one of my codeigniter controllers I have two methods, load_profile and edit_profile. edit_profile deals with form_validation when the user changes their profile info, and when the form is validated and data is submitted, I want to direct them back to their profile page via load_profile using `$this->load_profile()`.
However, now when their profile is loaded, the uri still says `/edit_profile`.
My question is how can I set it to load_profile instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redirect('load_profile')` for your purposes.

Additionally, you should include some sort of flashdata message and out put it when you redirect.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'your message');
```